# Xcode: NSUserDefaults dynamic Key

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to do a thing without success.
I don't know if it is a conceptual error or something else.

I'm saving some data in NSUserDefaults, but I would like to create keys dynamically because I can't know beforehand how many keys I will have so they will be created dynamically, depending on some other string.

This is to save data:

```
[defaults setObject:anObject forKey:@"aKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This is what I'm doing

```
NSString *myString = @"aString";
[defaults setObject:anObject forKey:@"%@",myString];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Unfortunately it returns
"Too many arguments to method call, expected 2, have 3"

Do you think is possible what I'm trying to do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify a format if the method wants NSString.

replace

```
[defaults setObject:anObject forKey:@"%@",myString];
```

with

```
[defaults setObject:anObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myString]];
```

or simply:

```
[defaults setObject:anObject forKey:myString];
```